# Is there a way to make an automatically updating string that is external from my application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to develop a software that has automatic / live notifications that can be updated and sent out to the user without having to push an update or hard-coding the notifications in the app. Below is a concept of what the notifications look like.

Is it possible to implement a feature like this without having to add external databases or API's?
[image: Full view of application + concept of Live Notification]

Comment: Yes. The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Would I need to connect an API to get a live updating system?

Comment: You would be better of reading [ask] and then coming back here with that knowledge in hand. I think then you'd be in a better position to get a great answer.

Comment: @Byron You can simply google your question. There are plenty of strategies for Push/Pull architectures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are defnitely better ways to solve this, but this is the most basic and simple way.

```vb
Public Shared Function Notification() As String
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim stream As Stream = client.OpenRead("Link to Text Goes Here")
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
    Dim content As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Return content
End Function
```

`Client` initializes the ability to access the web. The `stream` variable gets the text file or text from the remote website. The `reader` outputs the information into a StreamReader and `content` return it in a normal form.

Personally for my projects (which are now in C#), I use raw pastebin for the stream variable. This is because it's simple and takes a few seconds to setup. You could always use another website or another host that supports reading text files.

Updating the text is as simple as updating it through the text hoster (i.e editing through pastebin), and putting this function under a `Timer1_Tick` so everytime it ticks it gets updated from the server.

If you want to make it so that certain elements change when the string is a certain value, you can do something like this, for example a boolean.

```vb
Public Shared Function BooleanTest() As Boolean
    If Notification() = "Hello World!" Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```